# Can I turn off zoom-and-scroll behaviour of Adobe Reader's hand with down arrow pointer?

Tags: adobe-reader

This happens only on some PDF opened in Adobe Reader: when the mouse hand cursor is on a page, a down arrow appears in the middle of the hand, and when I click, it zooms in and scrolls one screen down. [image: Hand tool with arrow]

Can this be turned off? It's very annoying, I don't want it to change my zoom setting, and I don't want to scroll one screen down.

Comment: It is not the exact, optimal solution to your problem, but if you don't know about the great alternative, [Sumatra PDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) is a lightweight and much safer PDF reader. If you don't use any of Adobe Reader's extra features, there is little reason to use it as your default PDF rader. Just want to put it out there in case you don't know about it.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This feature is designed for [reading an article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Reader/8.0/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7fbc.html) in a newspaper or magazine PDF:

> In PDFs, **articles** are optional electronic threads that the PDF author may define within that PDF. Articles lead readers through the PDF content, jumping over pages or areas of the page that are not included in the article, in the same way that you might skim through a traditional newspaper or magazine, following one specific story and ignoring the rest. When you read an article, the page view may zoom in or out so that the current part of the article fills the screen.

To disable the Hand tool from following an article path, go to the the Edit menu and choose Preferences. In the General category, uncheck "Make Hand tool read articles".

Comment: As of Adobe DC 19 Bavi's fix *does not stop the hand tool from zooming and scrolling*.

Comment: Worked for me fine in 2020.

Comment: Works for me on Adobe Acrobat Reader DC v2020.009.20063.