# Adobe Reader Zooms on Left Click

Tags: zoom

I'm reading a document in Adobe Reader and it apparently has some setting built in so that if you click on the document then it zooms in one level for each click.  I can't even click on the scroll bar.  Does anyone know how to change this setting?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Right click anywhere on your document and make sure 'Marquee Zoom' isn't select instead of 'Select Tool'. You can also check this by going to View > Zoom > Marquee Tool

Comment: Do you have the hand tool with a down arrow? http://superuser.com/questions/207740/can-i-turn-off-zoom-and-scroll-behaviour-of-adobe-readers-hand-with-down-arrow/208084#208084

Comment: Thanks so much, Callen.  I had tried the view > zoom > etc but that was not working for some reason.  But the right-click menu did.

Comment: daxlerod -- it was showing a circle with a plus -- the usual small zoom icon.  I had seen that question (and a few others that were zoom related) but none of them fit my situation.

Comment: @CallenL: My Adobe Acrobat is showing the same irritating behaviour (it really gets in the way when adding comments) but the solution suggested here doesn't apply; the behavour continues when the Select Tool is selected. Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had the described problem, and I believe I found the same answer here, [Turn off a down arrow within the hand symbol in pdf](https://superuser.com/questions/647971/turn-off-a-down-arrow-within-the-hand-symbol-in-pdf)