# Turn off a down arrow within the hand symbol in pdf

Tags: pdf

While reading pdf files (with Adobe Reader XI) the hand symbol entails an arrow, showing down. If I make a click, the page moves. I find it pretty annoying and would like to turn the arrow off, but keep the hand symbol. I can't find any solution to it in the internet. Can someone help me to deactivate this function?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is probably due to the "Make hand tool read articles" setting.

You can switch it of by doing the following:

- Open menu item Edit > Preferences > General
- Uncheck "Make hand tool read articles"

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot upvote you... Thanks! :)

Comment: I cannot tell you the torture this silly Acrobat feature has caused me.  This worked!

Answer (score 0):

Some documents allow you to copy the text and have the Select Screen  symbol for a pointer. Some only have the hand. This is document, not software related. Open one of you other documents and the functionality returns.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1145918)

Answer (score 0):

- click on the avatar, next to the bell
- preferences
- general
- make hand tool read articles (uncheck it)
- scroll down and press <kbd>OK</kbd>

[image]